# Color every second row in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a table with some merged cells and I would like to color every second row, starting with the first, via a VBA code.

Thats how I tried it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Zeile As Long
    With Tabelle2
        For Zeile = 1 To .UsedRange(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 2
         .Range(.Cells(Zeile, 1),.Cells(Zeile,8)).Interior.ColorIndex= 15
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

And should look like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need VBA to do this, please see [How to shade every other row](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/919194/how-to-shade-every-other-row-in-excel). The nice thing about this method is that it is dynamic, so if you ever have to add additional rows, it's smart enough to notice it and change the following rows as well

Comment: @Maldred This doesn't appear to be every other row, so both the usual method of conditional formatting using `mod()` and OP's attempt using a `For` loop with `step -2` aren't going to cut it.

Comment: so the only problem are that the first cells are merged and cells G and H are not. My Idea was something with offset but I an VBA beginner so I cant bring my Idea in this Code.

Comment: @JNevill Ah yes, you're right. I missed that part, in that case then you will most definitely need VBA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this.

We add a boolean flag so we can flip back and forth using it (`cf`).

We can `Resize` the `MergeArea` instead of the cell value itself.

If there are merged cells, it will take that area into account - if not, it won't.

Then, add the potential `MergeArea` cell count to our row counter (`Zeile`).

```
Sub ColorEveryOther()
Dim cf As Boolean
Dim Zeile As Long
Dim lr As Long
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge
For Zeile = 1 To lr
    If Not cf Then Range("A" & Zeile).MergeArea.Resize(, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Zeile = (Zeile + Range("A" & Zeile).MergeArea.Cells.CountLarge) - 1
    cf = Not cf
Next Zeile
End Sub
```

Results:

[image: Results]

**EDIT:**

This is your code updated.

I also cleaned up the previous code a bit.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Zeile As Long
    Dim cf As Boolean
    With Tabelle2
        For Zeile = 1 To .UsedRange(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If cf = False Then .Cells(Zeile, 1).MergeArea.Resize(, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            Zeile = (Zeile + .Cells(Zeile, 1).MergeArea.Cells.CountLarge) - 1
            cf = Not cf
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Explanation from comments:

`cf = Not cf` is just a shortcut for:

```
If cf = True Then
    cf = False
Else
    cf = True
End If
```

Let's set `cf = False` and walk through it.

`cf = Not False` = `True`

`cf = Not True` = `False`

I hope that explanation is sufficient :)

The reason for doing this is we can't just `MOD` the Row because it changes by variable amounts potentially.

Comment: Thanks! It works :) but I dont under the cf part, could you explane how it works? Sounds intersting to be able to make an VBA code undid.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply - CF is just the variable name I picked - stands for `ColorFlag` - basically we only want to color every other row so we flip `cf` back and forth (between `True` and `False`) using `cf = Not cf` as we read through the rows. If it's `False`, we color the row. `cf = Not cf` is just a shortcut for `If cf = True Then cf = False Else cf = True End If` In one line you say, If it's True, become False, if it's False, become True. You can do this with many languages and VBA is no exception.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim Zeile As Double
Dim WhiteColor As Boolean
WhiteColor = False

Dim RangeSize As Byte

Range("A1").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
Zeile = ActiveCell.Row

Range("A1").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Row = Zeile + 1
    RangeSize = Selection.Count

    If WhiteColor = False Then
        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + RangeSize - 1, 8)).Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        WhiteColor = True
    Else
        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + RangeSize - 1, 8)).Interior.Color = vbWhite
        WhiteColor = False
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

I tried the code above and it worked for me:

[image]